# Camel and LRA Saga: when the compensation action is executed?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, saga, camel-spring-dsl, camel-saga

I would use the **Camel SAGA** component available at https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/saga-eip.html

I can easily understand that a "**compensation action**" is executed when the respective **SAGA action fails**, but it's not clear what is **the meaning of "failure"**.

I mean, on which basis does Camel mark a SAGA action as "failed"?
Is it considered failed when Camel throws an Exception?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever Camel execution breaks for a specific route – it could be when a `RunTimeException` is thrown or you set an exception in exchange – the compensation will be triggered automatically.